# Change an image src and show the new image on screen

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change an image src using jQuery pretty much like this..

```
 $('imgTest').attr("src", "http://www.mysite.com/pictures/gaz.jpg");
```

The image doesn't appear to change though - what else do I need for that to happen?

Thank,

Comment: Who did you steal this account from ?...

Comment: The stackoverflow account shop.

Answer (score 6):

if `imgTest` is an `id` attribute you should use `$('#imgTest')` instead

(or `$('.imgTest')` if it is a classname)

anyway you could avoid using jQuery for this simple task, in favour of "vanilla" javascript, e.g.

```
document.getElementById('imgTest').src = "...";
```

Comment: D'oh!:) can't believe i missed that. One of those days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to do something like

set according to `id` or `class` I just set here according to `id`.

```
$('#imgTest').attr("src", "http://www.mysite.com/pictures/gaz.jpg");
```

Hope it will help